# HTML code syntax pass rails 4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to make the following statement to code rails 4.1 `<a class='btn btn-contrast btn-lg fadeInRight animated' href='http://limanueva.cl/item/acd-website-html-template/5689597?ref=imagestudio'>`

Make the following change:

`<a class='btn btn-contrast btn-lg fadeInRight animated' href='<%= image_tag "fondos/fondo1.png" %>'>`

And does not show me the picture, please help

Comment: The href is where you link to, I assume you still want to link [here](http://limanueva.cl/item/acd-website-html-template/5689597?ref=imagestudio) but with the image as the link?  So you want `<a class='btn btn-contrast btn-lg fadeInRight animated' href='http://limanueva.cl/item/acd-website-html-template/5689597?ref=imagestudio' ><%= image_tag 'fondos/fondo1.png' %></a>`

Comment: The `href='http://limanueva.cl/item/acd-website-html-template/5689597?ref=imagestudio‌​' ` need to replace the following code: `<%= image_tag 'fondos/fondo1.png' %>`

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need you in the href can display an image on a route: **fondos/ fondo1.jpg** and no longer to the next test route: **http://limanueva.cl/item/acd-website-html-template/5689597?ref= Imagestudio**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= image_tag 'fondos/fondo1.png %>` - Outputs an html image tag.
**Example:** `<img src='path/to/fondos/fondo1.png'/>`

`<%= image_path 'fondos/fondo1.png%>` - Outputs the path to your image.
**Example:** `path/to/fondos/fondo1.png`

**If I understand correctly,** you want to display an image that links to a site.

```
 <a href='http://lima... ...9597?ref=imagestudio' class='classes for link'>
      <%= image_tag 'fondos/fondo1.png', :class => 'classes for image' %>
 </a>
```

**I did not understand correctly,** you want link to the image.

```
  <a href='<%= image_url 'fondos/fondo1.png'%>'>Link</a>
```

Comment: This HTML code: **`<a class='btn btn-contrast btn-lg fadeInRight animated' href='http://www.fondos/fondo1'>
                      Fondo 1
                    </a> `**  I need to convert the syntax rails 4 and the href that directs to a page I want change it to be routed to a picture of my project.